# Compile time error while passing the member of an array in Angular 4 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on angular 4 application . I am basically populated an array of type interface and trying to pass that array to getMinY function. I need to pass only the Yaxis data. How do i do that ? I am getting a compile time error when i do this.chartSeries.yaxis in line  let minY = this.getMinY(this.chartSeries);

```
export interface ChartSeries {
  yaxis: number[];
  data: number[];
}
   chartSeries: Array<ChartSeries> = [];
 minYAxis: number;
  maxYAxis: number;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.addSeries();
     let minY = this.getMinY(this.chartSeries);

  }

    private getMinY(data: any) {
    return data.reduce((min, p) => p.y < min ? p.y : min, data[0].y);
  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: property yaxis doesnt exist in chartseries []

Comment: I can do this this.chartSeries[0].yaxis but i need to pass all the yaxis arrays